# Docker understanding FROM part of the image

Tags: linux, docker, virtualization, dockerfile

After reading https://docs.docker.com/introduction/understanding-docker/ I am still having difficulty to understand the lightweight of the docker's containers.

Looking into a few of the public images, most of them are based on one of the following "base" images, like `FROM debian:jessie` or `FROM debian:wheezy`, there are also variants for ubuntu, I guess fedora and centos as well (there is also a "scratch" which is another topic).

So, considering this, I understand, that every docker container runs the base OS (mentioned in the image), so how does it work? Where is the lightweight comes from? Can you run the image based on, say, `debian:jessie` on fedora, and image based on `centos` on debian?

What about "scratch"? If you base your Dockerfile on "scratch" then you don't have OS running inside the container, so how does it work then in this case?

What is the relationship between Linux kernel of the host system and the docker container running on this host system?

Comment: "Runs"? That's a very loaded term. If you're not going through the init system, you're not really **running** the whole OS...

Comment: ...alternately, it could be argued that since all docker images are using your own kernel, you're **never** running any OS other than your own local one. :)

Comment: BTW, a collection of loosely-related questions does not a good StackOverflow question make. How are you (and how is anyone else) supposed to judge which answer is best / most canonical when some answers will answer some of your questions better than others? This kind of situation is part of why the "too broad" close reason exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where is the lightweight comes from?

Where the selected backend allows, an image is stored as a delta off its base -- so if you have several containers using the same base image, that base image is copied on-disk only once. Moreover, each image is reusing your host's kernel, and requires no hardware-level virtualization.

---

> So, considering this, I understand, that every docker container runs the base OS (mentioned in the image), so how does it work?

"Runs the X os" is really too vague to be a useful description; what you intend the word "run" to mean is, itself, unclear. Every application launched in a Docker environment is using the host's kernel, with filesystem contents (thus shared libraries, configuration, etc) provided by the container.

---

> Can you run the image based on, say, debian:jessie on fedora, and image based on centos on debian?

Yes. Any functionality that depends on the specific operating system's kernel will not be available.

---

> What is the relationship between Linux kernel of the host system and the docker container running on this host system?

The host system's kernel is the only one used; period.

---

> What about "scratch"? If you base your Dockerfile on "scratch" then you don't have OS running inside the container, so how does it work then in this case?

You have whatever software you insert into the container running with your host's kernel. It is, in this case, your responsibility to have that software set up to run without any components (like shared libraries) typically provided by a base image. This typically means that you need to have this software compiled as a static build, and not to depend on any OS-provided utilities (like a shell) unless you provide them yourself.

Comment: Hi, @charles-duffy, but how about as states in the article above "A container consists of an operating system, user-added files, and meta-data". And what is the purpose of OS images like debian, ubuntu, fedora, etc. available on docker hub then? If they are gonna to reuse the host kernel and resources anyway? What makes fedora image running on debian to behave like fedora, why would someone need these images at all? If it is clear what I mean.

Comment: "an operating system" is an unusably vague term. Whether an operating system is considered complete when used with a different OS's kernel is open to reasonable interpretation.

Comment: @zshamrock, ...and what do you mean, exactly, by "resources"? The libc is from the image; the configuration files and framework are from the image. That's enough to (for most purposes) behave more like that image than the host OS, despite the kernel being said host's.

Comment: ...the most important thing for typical (non-static-linked) application binary compatibility is shared libraries, which come from the filesystem, and the filesystem is *all* from the image unless otherwise specified.

Comment: Thank you, Charles Duffy, now it makes more sense and clear.